# How to work with regex in Pathlib correctly?

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

I want find all images and trying to use pathlib, but my reg expression don't work. where I went wrong?

```py
from pathlib import Path
FILE_PATHS=list(Path('./photos/test').rglob('*.(jpe?g|png)'))
print(len(FILE_PATHS))
FILE_PATHS=list(Path('./photos/test').rglob('*.jpg'))#11104
print(len(FILE_PATHS))

0
11104
```

Comment: Seems like you are mixing regex and glob syntax, the `rglob` function expects a glob selector as an arugment, not regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get list of files using Regex

```
import re
p = Path('C:/Users/user/Pictures')
files = []
for x in p.iterdir(): 
    a = re.search('.*(jpe?g|png)',str(x))
    if a is not None:
        files.append(a.group())
```

Answer (score 3):

Get list of files using `pathlib.Path` **then** filter list with regex using `re`

```
import re
from pathlib import Path
basepath = Path('C:/Users/user/Pictures')
pattern = '.*(jpe?g|png)'
matching_files = []

for _path in [p for p in basepath.rglob('*.*')]:
    if re.match(pattern, _path.name):
        matching_files.append(_path)
```

Comment: what's basepath?

Comment: @BND `basepath` is the path to search in. I've updated to codeblock. Thank you for  spotting the error.